# Continuity of $x^2y^2/(x^2+xy+y^2)$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I want to check whether the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+xy+y^2}$ with $f(0,0)=0$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

But due to term $xy$ in addition to squares in the denominator, I am unable to proceed.

Can one give some hint for it?

I tried to find partial derivatives.

Both partial derivatives are $0$ on $x$ as well as $y$ axis.

But at other points, we get as: $f_x=\frac{x^2y^3+2xy^4}{(x^2+xy+y^2)^2}$; I couldn't get any direction to see whether this partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ is bounded near $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take polar coordinates
$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^4\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta}{r^2(\cos^2\theta + \cos\theta\sin\theta + \sin^2\theta)} = \lim_{r\to 0} r^2 \frac{\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta + \cos\theta\sin\theta + \sin^2\theta}$$

For this limit to exist, we have to able to approach the same value for every direction. Does it happens in this case?

Comment: Yes; In the expression of $\theta$, the denominator is bounded below by $1/2$ and numerator bounded above by $1$, so expression in $\theta$ is a bounded quantity.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that $|f(x,y)| \leq |x||y| $.

[$|x||y|-xy \leq 2|x|y| \leq x^{2}+y^{2}$ by AM-GM inequality].

Answer (score 1):

Since $2|xy|\le x^2+y^2$
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+xy+y^2}\right|
&=|xy|\,\frac{2|xy|}{(x+y)^2+x^2+y^2}\\
&\le|xy|
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That is probably what Kavi meant with the hint.